# dropdownlist problem

Tags: drop-down-menu

I try to add a new item to the drodownlist.I want the added item to be place at first position of a dropdownlist.How can I do that

```
   I want this to be a first option
   ListItem itemspecial = new ListItem();
   itemspecial.Value = "-1";
   itemspecial.Text = "Please select specialization";
   ddlSpecialization.Items.Add(itemspecial);

    ddlSpecialization.DataTextField = "Description";
    ddlSpecialization.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlSpecialization.DataSource = objspecial.GetAll();
    ddlSpecialization.DataBind();
```

Comment: You may want to tag this question according to the technology/language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databind first before you insert...

```
ddlSpecialization.DataTextField = "Description";
ddlSpecialization.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlSpecialization.DataSource = objspecial.GetAll();
ddlSpecialization.DataBind();

ddlSpecialization.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select specialization", "-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the  `Insert` function of the `DropDownList`:

```
ListItem itemspecial = new ListItem();
itemspecial.Value = "-1";
itemspecial.Text = "Please select specialization";
ddlSpecialization.Items.Insert(0, itemspecial);

ddlSpecialization.DataTextField = "Description";
ddlSpecialization.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlSpecialization.DataSource = objspecial.GetAll();
ddlSpecialization.DataBind();
```

Answer (score -1):

use
-- ddlSpecialization.Items.insertAt(itemspecial,0);<-Specify the first index,